Optimizing PySpark Feature Engineering with Over a Billion Rows on EMR
I’m working with a large transaction dataset (~1 billion rows) in PySpark on AWS EMR. My goal is to perform feature engineering where I compute statistics like sum, mean, standard deviation, and entropy for different strata of data across various historical time periods.
I have a DataFrame called transactions_df with the following schema:
customer_id (String): Unique ID for each customer
transaction_date (Date): Date of the transaction
transaction_amount (Double): The amount of the transaction
transaction_type (String): Type of transaction (deposit, withdrawal, etc.)
I have to:
Create different strata of the data by applying conditions to the transaction types.
For each stratum, compute multiple statistics over different time periods (e.g., last 30 days, last 90 days).
Generate daily statistics for each customer within the given periods.
Here’s a simplified version of what my code looks like:
class FeatureEngineering:
    def __init__(self, transactions_df, strata_conditions):
        self.transactions_df = transactions_df
        self.strata_conditions = strata_conditions
        self.all_customers = transactions_df.select("customer_id").distinct()
        self.engineering_dates = (
            transactions_df.select("transaction_date").distinct().orderBy("transaction_date").collect()
        )
    
    def generate_strata_features(self, target_columns, time_periods):
        final_df = None

        for date in self.engineering_dates:  # Loop over each date
            for stratum_name, condition in self.strata_conditions.items():  # Loop over each stratum
                stratum_df = self.transactions_df.filter(condition)

                for col_name in target_columns:  # Loop over each target column
                    for period in time_periods:  # Loop over each time period
                        # Filter by the time period
                        filtered_df = self._filter_by_time_period(stratum_df, date, period)

                        # Compute statistics for the current time period and stratum
                        stats_df = self._compute_stats(filtered_df, stratum_name, period, col_name)
                        
                        # Join with the final dataframe
                        if final_df is None:
                            final_df = stats_df
                        else:
                            final_df = final_df.join(stats_df, on="customer_id", how="outer")

            # Add the date as a column to the final dataframe
            final_df = final_df.withColumn("engineering_date", F.lit(date["transaction_date"]))

        return final_df

    def _filter_by_time_period(self, df, date, period):
        """Filters the DataFrame based on the time period (e.g., last 30 days, last 90 days)."""
        return df.filter(
            (F.datediff(F.lit(date["transaction_date"]), F.col("transaction_date")) <= period) &
            (F.datediff(F.lit(date["transaction_date"]), F.col("transaction_date")) > 0)
        )
    
    def _compute_stats(self, df, stratum_name, period, col_name):
        """Computes stats like sum, mean, standard deviation, entropy, and Gini for a given stratum and period."""
        stats_df = df.groupBy("customer_id").agg(
            F.sum(col_name).alias(f"{stratum_name}_{period}_sum"),
            F.mean(col_name).alias(f"{stratum_name}_{period}_mean"),
            F.stddev(col_name).alias(f"{stratum_name}_{period}_stddev"),
            self._compute_entropy(df, col_name).alias(f"{stratum_name}_{period}_entropy"),
            self._compute_gini(df, col_name).alias(f"{stratum_name}_{period}_gini")
        )
        return stats_df
    
    def _compute_entropy(self, df, col_name):
        """Computes Shannon entropy for a given column."""
        total_count = df.groupBy('customer_id').agg(F.count(col_name).alias("total_count"))
        value_count = df.groupBy('customer_id', col_name).agg(F.count("*").alias("value_count"))
        df = value_count.join(total_count, on="customer_id").withColumn("prob", F.col("value_count") / F.col("total_count"))
        entropy_df = df.withColumn("entropy_component", -F.col("prob") * F.log2(F.col("prob")))
        return entropy_df.groupBy('customer_id').agg(F.sum("entropy_component").alias("entropy"))

    def _compute_gini(self, df, col_name):
        """Computes the Gini coefficient for a given column."""
        w = Window.partitionBy('customer_id').orderBy(col_name)
        df = df.withColumn("rank", F.sum(col_name).over(w))
        total_sum = df.groupBy('customer_id').agg(F.sum(col_name).alias("total_sum"))
        df = df.join(total_sum, on="customer_id").withColumn("norm_rank", F.col("rank") / F.col("total_sum"))
        df = df.withColumn("cum_norm_rank", F.sum("norm_rank").over(w))
        df = df.withColumn("gini", (2 * df.cum_norm_rank - 1) / df.count())
        return df.groupBy('customer_id').agg(F.mean("gini").alias("gini"))

Performance Issues
The issue I’m facing is that this code runs very slowly on my large dataset (~1 billion rows) and sometimes crashes with out-of-memory errors on EMR, even before the action that writes the results to S3. Running the generate_strata_features method takes hours to complete.
Key Problems:
Nested loops: I have nested loops over dates, strata, target columns, and time periods. This feels very inefficient, especially with PySpark's distributed nature.
Memory and Shuffle: Even though I'm using reasonably large executors, I still run into out-of-memory errors. I suspect it's due to too many shuffle operations from joins.
Slow performance: The feature engineering steps take hours even before I trigger the action to save the data as Parquet to S3.
My Questions:
How can I restructure this code to better leverage PySpark’s parallelism and avoid memory issues?
Are there any best practices for caching, checkpointing, or reducing shuffles that I should apply here?
How can I get rid of or minimize the nested loops while still generating the required features for each customer across multiple transaction strata and periods?
Any guidance on improving this process would be greatly appreciated!
Additional Information on the Code:
strata_conditions: Defines how to split the data into different strata (e.g., one stratum could be transaction_type == 'deposit').
generate_strata_features:
For each date in the engineering_dates list:

Filter the data to only include transactions for that date and stratum.

For each stratum and time period, compute statistics like sum, mean, standard deviation, entropy, and Gini for the target column(s).

Combine the results into a single DataFrame.


_compute_stats: Aggregates multiple statistics for each customer, including sum, mean, standard deviation, entropy, and Gini.
_compute_entropy: Calculates Shannon entropy for a given column.
_compute_gini: Calculates the Gini coefficient for a given column.
